# Unable to change font size in Python/tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, fonts, font-size

I tried to change fontsize in the python but it doesn't change at all no matter value of the fontsize

My code:

```
import tkinter


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("My First GUI Program")
window.minsize(width=600, height=300)

#Label

my_label = tkinter.Label(text="I am a label", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"))
my_label.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

The result:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG2p6.png)

Can anyone have any solution to fix this? I checked that the "Arial" font already installed on my system

Comment: Unable to reproduce

Comment: Your code works fine for me. When I change the `24` to some other number I get a different font.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think the issue here because I'm using a conda virtual environment, and it might not recognise the system fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on windows, you can go to `C:\Windows\Fonts` and find `Arial.ttf` and copy it to your project directory. I had this same problem a while back and this fixed it.